# use qrcode Making my app a device owner doesn't work

Tags: android

"I can successfully install an app using a QR code on my mobile phone, but when I try to do the same on my Samsung tablet (S8 Plus model), I get the following message: 'Due to a custom operating system installed on this device, this security policy prevents the creation of a managed device.' However, isn't the operating system on both devices Android? Why is this happening?"

Comment: Is this a store-brought Samsung tablet, or does it have (1) enterprise customization such as MDM, (2) third party modifications, e.g. rooted or perhaps (3) a foreign OS installed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.